# Jquery panel re-opens when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i made an exit button for a panel that goes full size when you click it, once the window "return to original size" animation is done. it does the "fullscreen the window" animation ? here is the JSFiddle link so you can look at it.

```
because for jsfiddle links you need a code section, here it is
```

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/txpmrv47/</strike>

Comment: You **have** to provide relevant code in question itself, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#exit-button').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // The rest of your code.
 });
```

#### Explanation:

You have a nested element, `#exit-button`, with a click event handler. It's parent also has a click event handler. Due to [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), the parent click handler gets called when the child element is clicked.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: that worked ! thanks ever so much dude ! i've been going at this problem all day xD. cheers !